# Why does the separator line still exists when I set the separator of the tableview is None?

Tags: ios

Firstly, I set the separator of the tableview is None.

Secondly, I set the separator of tableview cell is "Default Insets".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo7n2.jpg)

The result which I expected is that there is none separator, actually the result is that the separator still exists and, some of the separator are thicker than the others, it's so confused.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdaWO.jpg)

Comment: check once in device..

Comment: Are you sure you have set tableView separator as none in attribute inspector after selecting the tableview. Re-verify it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, that solved it for me:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set **Separator** to **None** as well as **SeparatorInsets** to **Custom(0,0)** for your TableView.

Also set **Separator** to **Custom Insets (0,0)** for TableViewCell.